# How to apply if statement to a Dataframe with input?

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have been trying to apply "if" function to a DataFrame. I'm asking the user to input the data number from the database and display specific data from the dataframe.

This is the code that I wrote for it

```
ask_persona = int(input("Starting from 0 to 250 which persona you wish to display ? ")) #Asking input to list the details of selected persona
display_persona.loc[ask_persona]
```

However I would like to improvise this idea of mine. There are 251 data(rows) and I would like to assign a condition that display an error message if the user's input exceeds 251 and wanna put it in a loop until user inputs the correct number or decides not to use it. I have tried many attempts and read many articles about indexing, if function in DataFrame and selection but failed.

My latest attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import_data = np.loadtxt('persona 5.csv', delimiter = ';' , dtype = object) #Importing file by creating string arrays by using dtype=object 
display_persona = pd.read_csv('persona 5.csv', index_col = 0) #Importing the data frame
pd.set_option("display.max_column", 15)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 251)
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None


ask_persona = int(input("Starting from 0 to 250 which persona you wish to display ? ")) #Asking input to list the details of selected persona
if ask_persona >  251 :
    print("Numbers must between 0 and 250")
elif ask_persona < 251:    
    display_persona.loc[ask_persona]
```

The output of this attempt displays nothing if the input is within the condition.

```
Starting from 0 to 250 which persona you wish to display ? 45
```

How do I apply "if" condition in this circumstance ? Thank you

Comment: There is missing `print` like `print (display_persona.loc[ask_persona])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in Jupyter notebook, you can use `display(display_persona.loc[ask_persona])` as your last line, otherwise `print(display_persona.loc[ask_persona])` will show the information.

If the information should be only from a specific column, you can change it to: `print(display_persona.loc[ask_persona, 'specific_column_name])`

Comment: Im so stupid that forgot printing. Thank you for the assistance